# Why does this elasticsearch range query appear to depend on the number of digits in the query?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have around 500,000 data files that have this structure:

```
{
"area": "testArea1",
"healthy": true,
"timestamp": "2016-02-10T14:38:20.979000",
"component": "appHealthCheck",
"day_of_week": 3,
"minute_of_day": 38,
"hour_of_day": 14
}
```

I've split out the minutes, hours and days so that I can run queries on time ranges. If I want to find all documents (using Kibana) where the value of hour_of_day is between 8 and 15, I should be able to use:

```
hour_of_day:[8 TO 15]
```

However, it returns no results. But if I do this:

```
hour_of_day:[8 TO 9]  OR hour_of_day:[10 TO 15]
```

I get the expected results returned. I've tried lots of combinations and it does appear to depend on the number of digits! I've created another index with fewer files - 7 - and I can use hour_of_day:[8 TO 15] as expected.

So I have a workaround, but I really want to know what might be causing this behaviour. Any thoughts?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure of your documents? ``hour_of_day:[8 TO 9]  AND hour_of_day:[10 TO 15]`` should not return any document.

Comment: I saw that and edited it! :) Typo in the question, not in kibana.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your index may not be treating `hour_of_day` fields as numbers. Please, check your [index mappings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) to make sure that you store them with appropriate [data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_field_datatypes)